# Words for boat, ship, and other seafaring vessels

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, vocabulario

In English, we have many words to describe the different types of vessels that travel on water:

- boat
- ship
- yacht
- dinghy
- canoe
- kayak
- raft
- watercraft
- vessel
- sailboat
- barge
- catamaran
- lifeboat/liferaft
- and other less common terms

Do these have direct translations into Spanish?

Also, what are the most common generic terms for a boat or ship, and what are the differences between them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> boat: barco, barca (smaller)
>
> ship: barco, buque
>
> yacht: yate
>
> dinghy: bote neumático
>
> canoe: canoa
>
> kayak: Kayac
>
> raft: balsa (Floating platform, originally formed by timbers together)
>
> watercraft:  embarcaciones (generic)
>
> vessel: navío
>
> sailboat: velero
>
> barge: barcaza
>
> catamaran: catamarán
>
> lifeboat/liferaft: bote salvavidas

The generic word for describe a board/ship in Spain is **barco**. But if you want do be more specific you could use other words like ship.

Comment: I didn't know the word *dinghy*, but it seems it's a *bote*, not necessarily *neumático*.

Comment: How does *lancha* fit in here?

Comment: @jrdioko "lancha" is a motorboat

Comment: "dinghy: bote neumático" - sorry, that's just wrong. "bote neumático" is inflatable boat.

Comment: "boat" can also be called "bote".