# Sinónimos del «barco»: embarcación, buque, navío, nave

Tags: vocabulario, sinónimos

En el libro que estoy leyendo se utilizan muchos sinónimos para un medio de transporte:

1. el barco
2. el buque
3. la embarcación
4. el navío
5. la nave

[Aquí](https://vadebarcos.net/2018/09/18/las-diferencias-entre-barcos-buques-navios-o-embarcaciones/), leyendo un poco sobre las diferencias entre los términos, lo que he comprendido es que:

1. *Barco* es la palabra «básica».
2. Un buque es un barco de mayor tamaño, capaz de navegar grandes distancias.
3. Un navío (= la nave?) es también un barco de gran tamaño.
4. Una embarcación es un barco menos grande.

No estoy tan interesado por la caracterización técnica de todos los términos, sino que no tengo ni idea de cómo se usa cado vocablo en la lengua corriente.

Comment: Mira también https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1478/14261.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Embarcación:** Es la palabra "básica", que se puede referir a todos los vehículos que van por el agua. Es de uso formal.

**Nave:** Como "embarcación", pero también puede referirse a vehículos aéreos, o espaciales (o a zonas dentro de un edificio). En el sentido de "embarcación", o de transporte aéreo, es formal. En el sentido de "nave espacial", no es necesariamente formal.

**Barco:** Es cualquier tipo de embarcación, salvo las más pequeñas. Es el término más común.

**Barca:** Es una embarcación pequeña, que se usa en ríos y lagos o en el mar muy cerca de la costa.

**Buque:** Como dices, es un barco grande que puede recorrer grandes distancias. Es formal, no se usa mucho en la lengua corriente.

**Navío:** Es más o menos lo mismo que buque, pero esta palabra se usa algo menos.

Todo esto es en la lengua común. No sé cómo se usan los términos en el ámbito técnico. Algunos están definidos en la legislación española (y supongo que de otros países), y esas definiciones no son necesariamente compatibles con las que yo he dado aquí.